# Apk/IPA size too large for Angular2 + cordova application

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, angular

I have created a sample angular 2 application and converted it into a hybrid app using cordova. Everything works fine , but the APK/IPA size is almost 33Mb. I didn't use any large images/files.  I guess it's due to the node modules present.Another problem is in iOS it takes much more time to build (Around 10 - 15 minutes). Can anyone suggest how to reduce the APK/IPA size so that the app can build and run fastly??